Do sidebands exist physically?
This is a concept that has puzzled me for a long time:
from the Wikipedia: "In radio communications, a sideband is a band of frequencies higher than or lower than the carrier frequency"
My question is: are these frequencies independent or are they constituents of the carrier wave? In other words, if I have the chance to analyze the modulated wave, would I see a wave changing its amplitude, or a lot of sine waves with different frequencies?


In other words, if I have the chance to analyze the modulated wave, would I see a wave changing its amplitude, or a lot of sine waves with different frequencies?

There's no difference between the two. The key insight of the frequency domain is that complicated signals are sums of sine waves with different frequencies.
Consider a sine wave modulated with a lower-frequency sine wave:
$$f(t) = \cos(10t)(1 + 0.25\cos(0.5t))$$
which looks like this:

Multiplying out the cosine gives:
$$f(t) = \cos(10t) + 0.25\cos(0.5t)\cos(10t)$$
There's a trig identity for multiplying cosines:
$$\cos(a)\cos(b) = \frac 1 2 \cos(a-b) + \frac 1 2 \cos(a+b)$$
We can apply this identity:
$$0.25\cos(0.5t)\cos(10t) = 0.125\cos(10t - 0.5t) + 0.125\cos(10t + 0.5t)$$
Plugging that back into our original function, we have:
$$\cos(10t)(1 + 0.25\cos(0.5t)) = \cos(10t) + 0.125\cos(9.5t) + 0.125\cos(10.5t)$$
Sure enough, if we graph the right side of that equation, we see the same modulated sine wave:

Which is the sum of the individual sine waves that make it up:

The same sort of thing happens with more complicated modulation schemes. So yes, the sidebands are physically real. You can build a narrow-band filter, feed the modulated signal into it, and have one of the sidebands come out the other end.

Carrier-suppressed amplitude modulation is a thing: transmitting only the sidebands saves power. Most commonly, only the sidebands on one side of the carrier are transmitted to save bandwidth, too (so-called "single sideband", "SSB"). So yes, the sidebands have an existence separate from the carrier.

if I have the chance to analyze the modulated wave, would I see a wave changing its amplitude, or a lot of sine waves with different frequencies?

Depends on what you analyze it with. If you look at an amplitude modulated wave with an oscilloscope, you'll see a sine wave changing its amplitude. If you look at it with a spectrum analyzer, it'll tell you the amplitudes of sine waves that add together to form the modulated wave.


Are these frequencies independent or are they constituents of the carrier wave? In other words, if I have the chance to analyze the modulated wave, would I see a wave changing its amplitude, or a lot of sine waves with different frequencies?

The term carrier wave refers to the single frequency wave that should be emitted so that the receiver can detect it and use it as the reference frequency/wave to demodulate the signal.  If it is not emitted then I call it the center frequency.
As such only one frequency is the constituant of the carrier wave.
Sidebands refer to the groups of frequencies that are on either side of the center frequency.  A sideband consists of a continous range of frequencies and there are an infinite number of frequencies in a sideband (there is also an infinite count of real numbers in any range, for instance [0,1] where we have 0.1, 0.100001, etc).
How the signal in the sideband evolves depends on the modulation.  In the case of a pure and perfect frequency modulation, the amplitude does not change. In the time-domain you will have difficulties to distinguish a single sine wave unless it's amplitude modulation and a precise tone is emitted.  In the frequency domain that would be a single line at a specific offset from the center frequency.
If you have a Frequency Shift Keying (FSK) modulation of a digital signal you would see a "sine wave" changing frequency in the time domain and two alternating vertical (Dirac) lines in the frequency domain in each sideband (so 4 lines in total).
Most of the time the signal just evolves continuously in both the time and frequency domains in a controlled manner but not resembling a particular sine wave.
So sidebands are not independent of a center frequency (potentially a carrier wave), as sidebands can only be on the side of a center frequency.  However, a carrier wave does not evolve because of what happens in a sideband - the combined signal evolves - a carrier wave provides the reference for the sideband signal and something for a receiver to lock on and to use as a sine wave for demodulation.

This is a concept that has puzzled me for a long time

It's difficult to know what is puzzling.  A lot of signals are modulated in a way that they fit in a reasonably limited bandwidth and they generally have a center frequency.
The modulation process generally implies that the emitted signal occupies the lower sideband and the higher sideband.  They are called "....band" because each occupies a continuous range of frequencies which is half of the total bandwidth of the signal.  They are called "side...." in reference to the center frequency.
The mystery could be about why we talk about sidebands.  I guess that is probably because when looking at at earliest modulations (AM) in the frequency domain, one could see the carrier wave and a symmetrical behavior of the signal strengths on either side of the carrier wave.  So an obvious result is that they were called sidebands.
While the sidebands were related at the start, nowadays we can have completely unrelated sidebands - except for having the same center frequency.  If we talk about sidebands, it supposes a center frequency but it does not imply that the other sideband holds a signal.

Do sidebands exist physically?

Waves are electromagnetics which is a branch of physics.  So as waves exist, they physically exist.  Because sidebands reference ranges of frequencies in which emissions occur, sidebands physically exist.

...Because sidebands reference ranges of frequencies in which emissions occur, sidebands physically exist. are sidebands emited ? or the electromagnetic wave have the form of the modulated carrier and the sidebands are only an analytical  representation of the electric field induced in the antenna wire ?

Sidebands are emitted and the receiver antenna captures a fraction of the power.  "The form of the elecromagitic wave" is 'analytical' as there is no 'form' for the wave - the form represents the evolution of the signal strength in a point over time, or the distribution of the signal strength in points across a line in space at a given time.
